# JavaScript in Angular | Event Binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a Twitter Bootstrap form that gets an orange border-bottom when it gets into focus. But the icon that is on the input line has its own border-bottom and i dont know how to bind the focus event in Angular to a function that makes the border-bottom of the icon also orange.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text" id="emailInputIcon"><i class="fal fa-envelope"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInputLogin" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="EMAIL">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                 <div class="input-group-text" id="passwordInputIcon"><i class="fal fa-key"></i></div>
             </div>
             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInputLogin" placeholder="PASSWORD">
         </div>
     </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **simple way** would be like this (simplified for readability):

HTML:

```
<input (focus)="onInputFocused()" (blur)="onInputBlurred()" />
<div class="icon" #icon></div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('icon') icon: ElementRef;

onInputFocused() {
    this.icon.nativeElement.style.borderBottom = 'orange 1px solid';
}
onInputBlurred() {
    this.icon.nativeElement.style.borderBottom = '';
}
```

---

**More elegant:**

HTML:

```
<input (focus)="onInputFocused()" (blur)="onInputBlurred()" />
<div class="icon" [ngClass]={'withBorder': focused}></div>
```

TS:

```
focused = false;
onInputFocused() {
    this.focused = true;
}
onInputBlurred() {
    this.focused = false;
}
```

CSS:

```
.withBorder {
    border-bottom: orange 1px solid;
}
```

---

**Without Angular, a plain CSS solution (preferable):**

HTML:

```
<div class="has-input">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.has-input input:focus + .icon {
    border-bottom: orange 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Where do you learned this? Do you have a tutorial for me to follow?